# rename a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a DF

```
df = spark.sql("""select number,name,owner,support,user,business_unit from table""")
```

I want to rename `owner.display_value` as `owner_display_value` and `support.display_value` as `support_display_value`

owner column and support column is a struct, hence i'm obtaining only the display_value from the column.

```
df2 = df.select("number","name","owner.display_value" as owner_display_value,"support.display_value" as support_display_value, "user_group","business_unit")
```

But I get error

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rename'.

Comment: your error does not match you code.

Comment: sorry, I get syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```py
df2 = df.select(
    "number",
    "name",
    "owner.display_value" as owner_display_value,
    "support.display_value" as support_display_value, 
    "user_group",
    "business_unit"
)
```

with

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "number",
    "name",
    "owner.display_value as owner_display_value",
    "support.display_value as support_display_value", 
    "user_group",
    "business_unit"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `F.col("column_name").alias("new_name")`:

Full example:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = StructType([
    StructField("number", LongType()),
    StructField("name", StringType()),
    StructField("owner", StructType([StructField("display_value", StringType())])),
    StructField("support", StructType([StructField("display_value", StringType())])),    
    StructField("user_group", StringType()),
    StructField("business_unit", StringType()),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[123, "abc", ("onwr",), ("sprt",), "usr", "bu"]], schema=schema)

df2 = df.select(
    "number", 
    "name", 
    F.col("owner.display_value").alias("owner_display_value"), 
    F.col("support.display_value").alias("support_display_value"),
    "user_group",
    "business_unit")

[Out]:
+------+----+-------------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+
|number|name|owner_display_value|support_display_value|user_group|business_unit|
+------+----+-------------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+
|123   |abc |onwr               |sprt                 |usr       |bu           |
+------+----+-------------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+
```